# Why should TCP socket be closed by server first?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am wondering whether the connection should be closed by the client or the server in TCP.

RFC6455 says the following

> The underlying TCP connection, in most normal cases, SHOULD be closed
> first by the server, so that it holds the TIME_WAIT state and not the
> client (as this would prevent it from re-opening the connection for 2
> maximum segment lifetimes (2MSL), while there is no corresponding
> server impact as a TIME_WAIT connection is immediately reopened upon
> a new SYN with a higher seq number).

Why should the client side avoid the TIME_WAIT state?
Is it because the server side can reopen with new SYN, while the client side can't, which leads to local port exhaustion?

Comment: did you mean [rfc6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455)?

Comment: Oh, that's right, I fixed it to rfc6455.

Comment: See [TIME_WAIT and its design implications for protocols and scalable client server systems](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)